# How to determine the number of elements in the same class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some elements in my website have the same class name
I want to know how many these elements with jquery or javascript?

Comment: `$('.className').length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code with jQuery

```
$('.class-name').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy with jQuery:

```js
console.log($('.text').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
<span class="text">TEST</span><br/>
```

**UPDATE**

The element `$('.text')` actually holds the array of all the classes `text` .

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$('.className').length
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className').length
```

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla javascript you can run:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className').length;
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('.className').length;
```

With jQuery:

```
$('.className').size()
```

or

```
$('.className').length;
```